Best way to present user details for review. Single vs multiple pages?
My application has 3 sections (20 pieces of data in total) and the user can part-complete an application and pick it up again later to finish. If I wanted the user to review their previously entered info to ensure it's still correct upon resuming the application, would it be ideal to present the info as one scrollable page with info grouped or 3 smaller pages?
This approach would need to work for users who originally entered the data a day ago and those who may have entered it a couple of weeks ago.


I will choose to show everything on one page because I, if I am the user, will want to see everything that I entered at once. Separating pages feels like I am doing another application hahaha (my personal opinion)
Although the page is quite long, I think it should be fine as long as the information is easy to read and the gestures to move around the screen are not too complicated.
Hope this help :)
